# How can I cast to IEnumerable<Guid> in simple.data?

Tags: c#, simple.data

I have this query in simple.data

```
var db = Database.Open();
IEnumerable<Guid> recetas = db.Factura
    .All()
    .Where(db.Factura.ObraSocialPlan_id == obraSocialPlanId)
    .Select(db.Factura.Id)
    .Cast<Guid>();
```

And I'm getting

> Cannot implicitly convert type `'Simple.Data.SimpleRecord'` to `'System.Guid'`

How should I change the query?

Comment: Sql data type is uniqueidentifier, it's a Guid and it's the primary key of the table Factura

Comment: I mean what type is db.Factura.Id declared as in the C# code. What is the .net type?

Comment: I don't have c# code for this, see the marked answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do this to an enumerable, but you can materialise it to a list like this:

```
var db = Database.Open();
IEnumerable<Guid> recetas = db.Factura
    .All()
    .Where(db.Factura.ObraSocialPlan_id == obraSocialPlanId)
    .Select(db.Factura.Id)
    .ToScalarList<Guid>();
```

If you want laziness, so you can pass the enumerable somewhere without having actually run the query, please raise an issue on the GitHub page: http://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data/issues

Thanks.